# QuartzCore drawtext issue in ios

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, quartz-graphics

my code draw this text upside down. Why?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.

CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;

UIGraphicsPushContext(myContext);



    CGContextSelectFont (myContext, // 3
                     "Courier",
                     24,
                     kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, 1); // 4
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFillStroke); // 5

   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, 1.0); // 6
   CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1); // 7
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, 100, 50, "Quartz 2D", 9); 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that CoreGraphics uses a coordinate system that has its origin in the lower left corner which is the Postscript convention. On iOS however the origin in in the upper left corner.

To use CoreGraphics you have to flip the coordinate system and shift the origin to the upper edge of the frame.

Here is how your drawRect method should look like.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.

    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;
    // flip transform used to transform the coordinate system from origin
    // top left corner to bottom right corner and inverting the y-axis
    CGAffineTransform flipTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.f, contextRect.size.height),
                                                              CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, -1.f));
    CGContextConcatCTM(myContext, flipTransform);

    UIGraphicsPushContext(myContext);



    CGContextSelectFont (myContext, // 3
                     "Courier",
                     24,
                     kCGEncodingMacRoman);
   CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, 1); // 4
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFillStroke); // 5

   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, 1.0); // 6
   CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1); // 7
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, 100, 50, "Quartz 2D", 9); 

}
```

Comment: You should be using a separate function for setting the transform for text: CGContextSetTextMatrix()

Comment: bleh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440825/does-cgcontextsettextmatrix-work-for-offscreen-bitmaps

Comment: Why should I? I concatenate two CTMs together so it works. Drawing text was not an issue.

Comment: I hate these frameworks! I think you're right, my second comment invalidates my first, I think.